# JMS Protocol is a text or binary

Tags: java, jms, protocols

I want to know what is the JMS protocol? is it text base protocol like http or a binary?
What is the hierarchy of these kind of protocols? ( RMI > JMS or ... )

I will thank you if you introduce me good reference for learning these protocols hierarchies.

RGDS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JMS message can be a BytesMessage, than the body of the JMS message is binary data.
Also the JMS message can be a TextMessage, than the body of the JMS message is string data.

JMS is completely *dependent* on the JMS Provider implementation. 
You have to first familiarize yourself with the [abstract specification](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/816-5904-10/816-5904-10.pdf&ei=AOM0T43sEMrjtQa5sPTXDA&usg=AFQjCNFurzLymRUxKrvSoBlYARS5S87Ing), than seek documentation depending on the JMS Vendor impl you're going to use. Most vendors follow the specification, but also extend it. I would say [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) and [HornetQ](http://www.jboss.org/hornetq/) are the most popular free license message brokers. Here's a [starting tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Ecommerce/jms/) on JMS, but if you have already chosen a specific vendor, it's best to follow their starting docs.

Comment: what is the provider in glassfish?

Answer (score 9):

JMS is an api specification, it doesn't define anything about the underlying protocol.

I would imagine that most JMS server implementations use a binary protocol, EMS which is the one I have had most experience with most certainly does.

Best place to start is the docs at [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/jms/tutorial/)

AMQP is a messaging standard which does however define the on the wire protocol, and it is binary.

Answer (score 5):

JMS is not a protocol. It is a specification. Many MOM vendors implement this specification and provide API for messaging. JMS implementations are vendor specific. So first understand JMS specs and then select your JMS provider.

Answer (score -1):

Its either - in fact JMS has two specific message types to cover those cases.

Id start with wiki - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service

And then take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/jms/tutorial/

Comment: It is neither. JMS is an API not a protocol. The protocol is up to the provider.